# Firefox bug or bad flex styling?

Tags: css, html, firefox, flexbox

I really have no idea where to begin solving this.

I have an app with nested flexboxes, each containing a range that has been rotated 270deg.

It works on chrome, but on firefox, it initially loads like this:
[image]

As you can see, disabled input type=numbers labeled as PPV(+) and NPV(-) are oddly pushed down. But, if I inspect the element, or resize the window, or other seemingly random triggers, it snaps back into correct positioning, looking the same as chrome:
[image]

Pen demonstrating the difference in chrome vs firefox can be seen at:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/RiverRockMedical/pen/pQVxbM)
Interestingly, removing either of these two styles negates the different rendering between browsers (both browsers display correctly).

`.inputDiv input[type=number] {font-size 1.3rem}`

And

`.inputDiv > .fuzzyDiv {margin-top: 15px}`

Anybody know what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Lots going on in your code. Can't dissect all of it right now.

But focus on this rule:

[image]

When you toggle off the `left: -126px`, the elements snaps into place.

Comment: Thanks for looking through the code ... I tried completely removing that line, and despite it breaking some of the rest of the layout, it didn't fix the problem at hand.

Comment: See if you can reproduce the problem with minimal code in a jsfiddle or codepen demo. Then post that code in your question. Others may then assist, and your question won't be closed for violating the guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for the polite tone - I feel like a complete idiot for not thinking of it first. I'm still working on cutting things to make it "minimal", but I've updated my question with a link. Found a few things that fix the effect, but still not sure why.